# Plotting a 2D heatmap and a normal 2D plot together in GNUplot

Tags: gnuplot, heatmap

I have multiple number of .dat files, that I use to create a 2D heatmap in GNUplot. They consist of three columns. This is the script I'm using :

```
set terminal png size 1920,1080 enhanced font 'Verdana,35'
se output 'IPR_alpha-05_new.png'
se xl '{/Symbol l}'
se yl 'Energy'
se title 'IPR of Maryland model,{/Symbol a} = -0.5'
se view map
filename(n)=sprintf("IPR_tr_p%ialpha-0.5.dat",n)  
splot for [i=1:56] filename(i) u 1:2:3 with points pointtype 5 pointsize 1 palette linewidth 30 notitle
```

Now, I have another file, from where I would like to create a simple 2D plot and merge that on top the heatmap plot. The X and Y axis for both these plots are same. I tried to add a simple command like :

```
pl 'filename.dat' u 1:2
```

after the splot command in the previous script, but it seems like the process quits after executing the splot command.

Please tell me how can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use a 3D plotting command (`set view map; splot...`) to make a 2D heatmap.  So the solution to your problem is to use `plot` rather than `splot` for both the heatmaps and the superimposed line plot:

```
  plot for [i=1:56] filename(i) u 1:2:3 with points pt 5 lc palette, \
       'filename.dat' u 1:2 with lines
```